# Olympus TV series: full form and meaning of "It was all I had growing up."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, ellipsis

I was watching "Olympus" TV series. A character says that "It was all I had growing up."

"It was all I had (when I was) growing up."
Is that the completed sentence of it? If so, when and how can we omit words in speaking? What are the rules of omitting?

Comment: Your understanding of the sentence is correct.  I think the general question of when words can be omitted in English can't be easily answered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your interpretation of the sentence is correct. People sometimes omit the words that they consider too obvious. The presence of such a word is implied but it isn't included in the sentence. You will find many instances of this in verbal as well as written communication.

As for when to omit, here's a [helpful link](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/a-guide-to-elliptical-constructions/).

Hope this helps.